# Making/forcing the Validation to fail by adding custom error Not Working in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, validation, custom-errors

I am trying to make the Validation fail. I have tried the following:

**UserController.php**

```
public function add_user(Request $request)
{
$messsages = array(
    'email.unique' => 'Email already exists',
    'email.required' => 'Email is missing',
    'valid_from.date_format' => 'Valid from date invalid. mm/dd/yyyy e.g. 12/13/2014',
    'valid_to.date_format' => 'Valid to date invalid. mm/dd/yyyy e.g. 12/13/2014',
    'valid_to.required' => 'Valid to date is missing',
    'cnic.min' => 'CNIC is 15 characters long. Do not forget hyphens 35212-XXXXXXX-X',
    'cnic.max' => 'CNIC is 15 characters long. Do not forget hyphens 35212-XXXXXXX-X',
    'cnic.regex' => 'CNIC include hyphens 35212-XXXXXXX-X'
);

$rules = array(
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
    'valid_from' => 'required|date_format:m/d/Y',
    'valid_to' => 'required|date_format:m/d/Y',
    'phone' => 'numeric',
    'cnic' => [
    'min:15',
    'max:15',
    'regex:/\d{5}-\d{7}-\d{1}/'
    ]
);

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messsages);

//Check year
$y_from = substr($request->valid_from, -4); $y_from = (int)$y_from;
$y_to = substr($request->valid_to, -4); $y_to = (int)$y_to;
if($y_from >= 2038 || $y_to >= 2038) //HERE I ADD CUSTOM ERROR
{
    $validator->getMessageBag()->add('maxyear', 'Invalid date. Maximum value of Year = 2038');
    //$validator->errors()->add('maxyear', 'Invalid date. Maximum value of Year = 2038'); //Doesnt work as above
}

if ($validator->fails()) { //DOESNT WORK
    $messages = $validator->messages();
    return Redirect::route('userAdd')->withErrors($messages);
}

$user = new User;
$user->name = $request->name;
/* Save other model data */

$user->save();
Session::flash('userCreated', 'User Created Successfully');

return redirect('/pending_users');
}
```

The *$validator->fails()* goes true somehow and validation does not fail..

I have tried a solution like:

```
if($y_from >= 2038 || $y_to >= 2038)
{
    //$validator->getMessageBag()->add('maxyear', 'Invalid value for Year in date. Max year = 2038');
    //$validator->errors()->add('maxyear', 'Invalid date. Maximum value of Year = 2038');
    $rules['unreal_input'] = 'required'; 
    $messages['unreal_input.required'] = 'Invalid date. Maximum value of Year = 2038';
}

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messsages);
```

It is Ugly as in View it always gives default error "unreal_input is required field". HELP!!

**UPDATE**

It was typo I used $messsages with 3 s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changes are good so that you add `$rules['unreal_input']` and `$messages['unreal_input.required']`

However you are having a typo, See $messsages vs $messages. In one case there are 3x "s" other case there are only 2x so it is different array.

Comment: Thank you!  and can u help figure out why the generally proposed way i.e $validator->errors()->add() is not able to make the validation fail?

Comment: getMessageBag()->add() is does not affect validation logic, Validation failure depends on $request->all() and $rules values only on your code.